# Create Geographic Reference for X,Y Coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, xy

I have a set of x,y data that do not have any sort of geographic reference.  I have lat/longs (WGS 84) for a small set of those points.  How can I calculate lat/long for the remaining points so I can get them geographically placed?  Thanks!

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Are you confident that the points you have in your reference set (where you have both cartesian and geo-referenced) are really representative of the whole cartesian set?

Answer (score 1):

Map the points that have lat / long coordinates, then create X Y fields and populate them with the coordinates from the most likely coordinate systems.

In ArcMap you can set the data frame's coordinate system then use the Calculate Geometry option in the attribute table to populate the fields.  When you get a match you've found you're coordinate system.

In QGIS you'll need to enable on the fly projection in the project properties, then you can set the coordinate reference system.  Once it is set you can go into the attribute table and use the field calculator to set the X and Y values for your fields.

Do you know the extent of the points?  That can help you narrow it down if you know they are in a particular country or state.

Answer (score 0):

Use arcmap to reproject the set with latlon to a projection that will cause the least amount of rotation,scale, stretch to the rest of the data.
This is going to take some discernment.
Load the entire set by themselves with no projection set.
Zoom to the extents.
Add a polygon of (optimally) a single polygon like a county boundary (with a verified projection).
Set the map document projection (right click on the layer data frame in the table of contents).
This is the discernment part.
Keep changing this to different types of systems. (You can zoom to extents) to see if the poly gets close to the unprotected data.
Try an Albers meter, state plane feet, sinusoidal, just blow through a bunch.
All you are trying to do is get them close to where they should be.
If you get lucky and find one that is exact then you're good.
If not then...
More work.  If you know some of the outside points (like a ring around your data) and where they are on the ground, use the previous exercise,
Add an aerial or arcgisonline imagery.
Use the spatial adjustment tool. Like this [esri tutorial](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t00000024000000.htm) and [transform](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Exercise_5a_Transforming_data/001t00000023000000/) might work better.
Finally set your document projection to the projection you desire the output of your unprojected data to be.
Right click on it and use data> export.
Select the same as data frame option to reproject the data.